# Zwei 20- und 25-jährige Täter

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Die Polizei konnte zwei 20- und 25-jährige Täter festnehmen.

Bedeutet das nicht, dass die Polizei zwei Täter festgenommen hat, die jeweils 20 und gleichzeitg 25 Jahre alt sind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doch, klar, das bedeutet es, wenn man es genau nimmt.

Korrekt wäre zum Beispiel:

> Die Polizei konnte zwei 20- **bzw.** 25-jährige Täter festnehmen.

Ich halte das "und" allerdings für eine hier gut verständliche und deshalb zulässige Vereinfachung. "Beziehungsweise" ist, vor allem gesprochen, ein etwas sperriges Wort.

Naheliegende Alternative, für die ein Autor allerdings das Geschlecht der Täter kennen muss/sollte:

> Die Polizei konnte zwei Täter festnehmen, einen 20- und einen 25jährigen.